Android TextView with time on the last line
I need a custom textview that would display the time on the last line. The time should be aligned to the right of the all message. If there is no space on the last line, then the time is moved below. Are there libraries for this to be implemented? Or how to do it yourself?

Assuming this is your TextView in xml :
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMain"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

You can achieve that by doing some calculations and checks on width, here is an example function which you can pass to the main text, and the timestamp
private fun updateText(mainText: String, timestamp: String) {
    val fullText = "$mainText $timestamp"
    textViewMain.text = fullText

    textViewMain.post {
        val layout = textViewMain.layout ?: return@post
        val textWidth = layout.getLineWidth(layout.lineCount - 1)
        val timestampWidth = textViewMain.paint.measureText(timestamp)

        if (textWidth + timestampWidth > textViewMain.width) {
            // Not enough space to fit on one line, put timestamp on a new line
            val newText = "$mainText\n$timestamp"
            val spannable = SpannableString(newText)
            spannable.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(0.9f), newText.length - timestamp.length, newText.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            textViewMain.text = spannable
        }
    }
}


Thanks. But I need to align timestamp on the right side.
